# How can I set installLocation depending on Android version?

Tags: android

Is it possible to specify the installLocation attribute depending on Android version?

For example, I have an app with a simple widget that has installLocation set to "preferExternal". On Froyo and JellyBean the widget is visible in the drawer, but on ICS I need to move the app to the phone's internal memory in order to have the widget available in the drawer.

Is there a way to set installLocation for devices with ICS only to "internalOnly" and keep the "preferExternal" for devices with Froyo and JellyBean?

Comment: I don't think so. I read all of following page but there was not this feature. Please look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html), it seems like it's not possible- at least not simply.  If there is a simple way to do this, I don't know it- perhaps another user can help with that.

However, if you're willing to make your life a little bit complicated, Google Play does support uploading multiple versions that are accessible only on different devices.  You could have one version which is only for minimum API level 14 and up, in which the manifest is set to

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

and another version for all other APIs that is exactly the same except for having

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Alternatively, you could just set install location to auto- this will make it install on the phone by default while still giving users the option to switch it to external.  But as far as I can tell, the functionality you're asking for can be done in this way- it just makes your life a pain